# How to publish offline odoo website for public viewing on Windows domain server

Tags: python, windows, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have designed a small, simple and static website offline in odoo 8. It is on my computer: Localhost.

I want to transfer these files to domain server which is on Windows and database in MySQL.

Which files I have to pick up from my PC to transfer to web server?

What is the path for these files? (Right now I can see files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150526. But I am not able to find website module files e.g. images or index etc.).

Can you help me by steps how and which files to pick up and upload through FTP like Filezilla?
Will Python site work on Windows Server?

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple you dont need to copy `python` any files, thats not right way in odoo, right way is as following.
First Deploy the same version of Odoo from nightly to your domain and then take back-up of your local instnace with "Zip (inclues filestore)" option. and then restore that copy on your domain instance.

Guide to How to [Backup and Restore](http://www.knowledgement.ie/en_US/general/how-to-create-backup-of-the-database-and-restore-the-database-in-openerpodoo)

Bests

Comment: Do i need to install odoo instance on server or just copy local odoo files on server ?